# Sorting lua tables by arbitrary values

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have a table with the following structure:

```
table = {
    [1] = {"something", "high"}
    [2] = {"something else", "low"}
    [3] = {"something further", "medium"},
    [4] = {"yet more something", "medium"},
}
```

What I want to do, is to use a delegate function to sort that table with table.sort() so that the priority variable (high, low, medium, etc) orders the list with high being followed in the list, followed by medium and then low. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to know how `table.sort` works, so where are you stuck?
Simply create a lookup table that translates priority names into integers and compare those:

```
priorities = {high = 2, medium = 1, low = 0}
table.sort(t, function(e1, e2)
    return priorities[e1[2]] > priorities[e2[2]]
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.sort(t, 
  function(e1, e2)
    return e1[2]:sub(-1) < e2[2]:sub(-1)
  end
)
```

Comment: Funny idea, but quite obscure and inflexible, don't you think?

Comment: I just wanted to add a note of caution, as this is a very compact solution but one that I don't think should go into production code ;)

Comment: @Ephemeralis - Please don't embed my solution into production code :-)